# Why my sql queries in Excel are slow?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I use a function to query a database and return the result in excel. I call the function 3 times and it takes about 15 minutes to return all the data. The same queries I execute in Aqua Data Studio and get the result in 20 seconds per query.

I can't understand why in excel it is so slow. How can improve the speed, is it possible to change the code so that it can be executed faster?

Here are my functions written in VBA. The first one is called in the second one.

```
Function MyQuery(ConnString As String, ByVal QueryString As String, MyDestination As Range, DispName As String) As Boolean
'
' MyQuery(ConnString, QueryString, MyDestination, DispName)
'

   With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=ConnString, Destination:=MyDestination).QueryTable
        .CommandText = QueryString
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = DispName
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    MyQuery = True
End Function
```

And here is the second function in which I write the SQL:

```
Sub GetData(DestinationRange As Range, QueryTableName As String, Lacs As String, Racs As String, StartTime As String, EndTime As String, Capacity As String)
'
'GetData(DestinationRange, QueryTableName, Lacs, Racs, StartTime, EndTime, Capacity)
'

Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim FuncFeedback As Boolean

ConnectionString = "ODBC;DSN=PostgreSQL30;DATABASE=xxxx;SERVER=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;PORT=5432;UID=xxxxx;;SSLmode=disable;ReadOnly=0;Protocol=7.4;FakeOidIndex=0;ShowOidColumn=0;RowVersioning=0;ShowSystemTables=0;ConnSettings=;Fetch=100;Socket=4096;UnknownSizes=0;MaxVarcharSize=255;MaxLongVarcharSize=8190;Debug=0;CommLog=0;Optimizer=0;Ksqo=1;UseDeclareFetch=0;TextAsLongVarchar=1;UnknownsAsLongVarchar=0;BoolsAsChar=1;Parse=0;CancelAsFreeStmt=0;ExtraSysTablePrefixes=dd_;;LFConversion=1;UpdatableCursors=1;DisallowPremature=0;TrueIsMinus1=0;BI=0;ByteaAsLongVarBinary=0;UseServerSidePrepare=1;LowerCaseIdentifier=0;GssAuthUseGSS=0;XaOpt=1"


Query1 = " SELECT "
Query1 = Query1 & "TIMESTAMP::DATE::TEXT, "

'...
' AND HERE I WRITE THE SQL QUERY THIS WAY, THE WHOLE QUERY IS NOT INCLUDED
'...

Query1 = Query1 & " WHERE "
Query1 = Query1 & " (TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '" & StartTime & "' AND '" & EndTime & "')"  


FuncFeedback = MyQuery(ConnectionString, Query1, DestinationRange, QueryTableName)
            ' MyQuery(ConnString, QueryString, MyDestination, DispName)

End Sub
```

Comment: It's not VBA, it's the connection. Experiment with different ways to connect to your database. You might find an acceptable alternative. This might help you going: [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Give [MS Power Query](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379&WT.mc_id=Blog_PBI_Announce_DI) Add-In a try. It's very performant to grab datas from different sources. You can also transform the collected datas before loading them in Excel als table.
Power Query has some use limitations depending of the version of Excel 2013 (e.g. Professional) you use.